# Service is not getting injected into Grails domain class , Grails 2.0.0 and 2.0.3

Tags: spring, grails

I've tried multiple app restarts, and upgrading from 2.0.0 to 2.0.3, no help.  I always get this message:

```
:   def getCustomerName(){64:       customerService.name
"Cannot get property 'name' on null object"
```

Relevant domain class part:

```
class Instance {
    def customerService
    ...

    def getCustomerName(){
        customerService.name
    }
```

Relevant Service class:

```
class CustomerService {
```

I'm trying to access the getCustomerName method from a view which has access to an object of Instance. Also tried this with another service, same result.

Comment: Is your service class source file in the `grails-app/services` subdirectory?

Comment: It is. I should also mention that CustomerService injection is working in the Controller, just not in the Domain object.

Comment: Have you tried doing a grails clean and then running your app. If it works in Controller it should, can't think of anything else.

Comment: grails-clean in STS doesn't fix the problem, only seems to delete a certain "plugin-classes" dir that I had to hunt down and replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess here - the following reads like a getter method:

```
    def getCustomerName()
```

Is it possible that the framework is checking the getter and setter methods for validity before the dependency injection takes place?

Burt answered a question a couple of years ago regarding using dependency injection in an onLoad() and it appeared that is what was happening.  He advised:

Add this import:

```
    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH
```

and then reference the customer service as

```
    def customerService = AH.application.mainContext.customerService
```

Comment: Renamed method to "test", same result.  Fortunately (and unfortunately) your suggestion of reverting to manual injection works, so I guess I'll live with the AH deprecation warning for the time being. This seems like a Grails bug to me, think I should report it?

Comment: It certainly seems like a bug to me.